# OpenMP using single thread only

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2017, openmp

I tried to run this code using MS visual studio 2017 and my CPU has 48 threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
   {
      int i = omp_get_thread_num();
      printf_s("Hello from thread %d\n", i);
   }
}
```

I was hoping to get output like this

```
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 3
```

But actually I am getting this output

```
Hello from thread 0
```

So far I have done following things

1. Enable openMP in the project settings:Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> OpenMP
2. Set environment variable OMP_DYNAMIC to FALSE

My question is what I am missing? Why it is not printing output from multiple threads?

Comment: With so little work to do per thread, it would seem silly to incur the overhead of spawning individual threads versus just running everything on the same thread. I'm *guessing* that your OpenMP implementation or compiler is just being clever and realising that using multiple threads here would only *hurt* performance. Purely a guess though.

Comment: I'm guessing you have visual studio setting that is goofing you up (e.g. runtime build different from debug build or something of the sort). If you have visual studio you should be able to find a "Developer Command Prompt for VS*" so you can make sure the compile is right and not bogged down in MSVC settings. Compile with e.g.

cl /openmp hello.c

Comment: Since we are pretty sure it is a compiler issue, I undeleted my initial answer to show where you can enable openmp in visual studio, and hopefully it will be a true answer.

Comment: @Thomas this is not how OpenMP works. The parallel region executes in all threads and the code shown should produce the output shown if compiled properly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not aware of any compiler which ignores OpenMP pragmas when enabled based on optimisation assumptions, moreover when it will go directly against the OpenMP specification.

Answer (score 1):

You have a visual studio setting that is goofing you up (e.g. runtime build different from debug build or something of the sort). If you have visual studio you should be able to find a "Developer Command Prompt for VS*" so you can make sure the compile is right and not bogged down in MSVC settings. Compile with e.g.

```
cl /openmp hello.c
```

In visual studio, you'll want to make sure the omp support is enabled by going to the project properties (Alt F7), and Language tab then enable Open MP Support.
[image]

Comment: If OpenMP support wasn't enabled, the program simply won't compile - `omp_get_thread_num` is not in any library linked by default. Unless turning the support on and off leaves the OpenMP runtime in the additional libraries in the linker settings.

Comment: @HristoIliev you'd think so, but however MS is compiling it links to the library and just doesn't use it. If Open MP language support is off, there's no multithreading, and if it's on you get what you'd expect. Happens both in VS IDE and on prompt.

Comment: Indeed, there is a `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` in `omp.h` that results in the OpenMP runtime being linked in by merely including the header. Microsoft always have their own way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing something:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46728001806b62d5)**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        printf("Hello from thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 1
```

Pay particular attention to the compiler flags:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -fopenmp main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Comment: .Not sure I understood your solution. Did you mean I need to use gcc compiler instead of MS visual studio 2017 compiler?

Comment: @mohammad.roni What I'm saying, and what sehe is saying is that your code is fine, so something else is wrong. My guess, see my comment to your original post, is that your compilation is wrong.  As in my comment, I'd suggest opening up a Developer Command prompt and compile using  the "cl /openmp hello.c" command (obviously navigate to the right path and such). Then run the hello.exe it generates. If that works then you're MSCV configuration need works.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren you are right and thanks for your solution. I compile using "cl /openmp hello.c" commnad and it worked. Any thought what kind of  MS Visual Studio  configuration would be needed if I were to avoid command prompt.

Comment: @mohammad.roni you probably have to fill in "/openmp" in generic textbox in the compile settings dialog. Also, make sure it applies to all build variants

Comment: @mohammad.roni You should be aware that if you are using Microsoft's compilers (rather than some other compiler accessed via VS), they only support a very old version of OpenMP 2.0 [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=vs-2019 ], Since OpenMP is now up to 5.0 you are missing a lot...